# Spring application properties ignoring slashes in strings

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when loading external properties to the spring boot (`2.0.3.RELEASE`) application using `application.yaml`. I will show a minimal example bellow. I have defined a `@ConfigurationProperties` class as follows:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
class ConfigProperties {
    var testString: String = ""
    var testMap : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
}
```

I also have an adequate `application.yaml` file:

```
testString: "/profile/test"
testMap:
    "/profile/main" : "Welcome/to/profile"
```

When evaluated, `ConfigProperties.testString` produces `/profile/test` as expected but `ConfigProperties.testMap` produces a map of size one with the only entry's key set to `profilemain` and value set to `Welcome/to/profile`. Why does the key ignore a forward slashes (`/`) but value is resolved properly? I tried escaping the forward slash but that didn't work. I also found that other special characters like colon (`:`) and backslash (`\`) also get ignored by the map key.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but if someone else is wondering, this is how it works in spring boot 2.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#relaxed-binding

```
For map keys with non-alphanumeric characters (other than -) in them, surround the key name with []. For example:
spring:
  my-example:
    '[foo.baz]': bar
    '[abc xyz]': def
```